# Creating a function in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function

I have some problem with creating a function to my Rails app.

I want it to work like this:

```
str = "string here"
if str.within_range?(3..30)
puts "It's withing the range!"
end
```

To do that I added this into my application helper:

```
def within_range?(range)
  if self.is_a?(String)
    (range).include?(self.size)
  elsif self.is_a?(Integer)
    (range).include?(self)
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `within_range?' for &quot;&quot;:String
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Switching on class identity in an OO language is weird. Just define the String version on String and the Integer version on Integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Hello, i have some problem with creating a function to my Rails app.

Uh oh, right there we run into our first misunderstanding: Ruby is not a *functional* programming language. It is an *object-oriented* programming language. There is no such thing as a function in Ruby. Ruby only has *methods* that live on *classes*.

> ```
> str = 'string here'
> puts "It's within the range!" if str.within_range?(3..30)
> ```

Here we can see that you obviously intend to have your method available on string objects. In order for your method to be available on string objects, it needs to be defined on the `String` class (or any of its ancestors).

> To do that i added this into my application helper:
>
> ```
> def within_range?(range)
>   if is_a?(String)
>     range.include?(size)
>   elsif is_a?(Integer)
>     range.include?(self) 
>   end
> end
> ```

Here, you are adding the `within_range?` method to the anymous top-level object and not to the `String` class. Adding a method to the anymous top-level object, also makes it "magically" available as a private method on the `Object` class which is the superclass of (almost) all classes. Therefore, `within_range?` is now available on all objects, but it is private, so you can only call it with an implicit receiver.

Which is why I don't understand why you are getting this error:

> But i get this error:
>
> ```
> undefined method `within_range?' for "":String
> ```

There's two things wrong here: first, the object that Ruby reports the error on should be `"string here":String`, not `"":String`. This means that you were actually calling the `within_range?` method on an *empty* string and *not* on the string `'string here'` as your code sample shows. Which means that *somewhere else* in your code base, *before* the code sample that you posted here, `within_range?` *already* gets called on an empty string.

The second problem is that you are getting the totally *wrong* error message. Ruby tells you that Ruby couldn't find a `within_range?` method for strings, i.e. that there is no `within_range?` method on the `String` class or any of its superclasses including `Object`. But there *should* be! You *did* (although accidentally) define a private method on `Object`. The error message that you *should* be getting is this:

```
NoMethodError: private method `within_range?' called for "string here":String
```

This means that the code that defines the method never actually got executed. I am not familiar enough with Ruby on Rails to diagnose why that may be the case, though.

But now on to the contents of the code itself. Like I hinted at above, you need to add this code to the `String` class. And actually, *inside* your method, you are dealing with both strings and integers, so you need to add the code to a common superclass of `String` and `Integer` and there is only one and that is `Object`:

```
class Object
  def within_range?(range)
    if    is_a?(String)  then range.include?(size)
    elsif is_a?(Integer) then range.include?(self) end
  end
end
```

[I took the liberty of removing a couple of extra parentheses, `self`s and newlines.]

There are a couple of problems with this. First: `is_a?` in Ruby is a Code Smell. It almost always means that you are either doing something wrong or at least something "un-Rubyish", like trying to re-implement static typing. (Don't get me wrong: I like static typing, but if I need it, I use a more appropriate language than Ruby.)

In general, if you find yourself using `is_a?` or its cousins `kind_of?` and `Module#===`, you should take a step back and reconsider your design.

Another problem with your code is that you have a condition that examines `self`. This is even easier to see when we refactor the code to use a `case` expression instead of an `if` expression:

```
class Object
  def within_range?(range)
    case self
    when String  then range.include?(size)
    when Integer then range.include?(self) end
  end
end
```

Here, it is easy to see that the object is looking at itself. It should *never* need to do that! It should always already know everything there is to know about itself. That's as if you had to look in the mirror to know what you are wearing: you shouldn't need to do that, after all you put the clothes on yourself! (And if you need to do that, it is probably the result of some bad decision the night before, just like in programming ...)

A third smell here is the fact that you are doing different things, depending on the type of an object. That's exactly what polymorphism is for: if you say `foo.bar`, Ruby will call a different version of `bar`, depending on what the type of `foo` is. There's no need for you to re-implement this yourself, it's already there.

So, let's step back: what is the method actually doing? Well, if it's called on a string, then it does one thing and if it's called on an integer, it does another thing. So, we are lazy and let Ruby do the work of figuring out which of the two to run:

```
class String
  def within_range?(range)
    range.include?(size)
  end
end

class Integer
  def within_range?(range)
    range.include?(self)
  end
end
```

This is already much simpler and much clearer. And there is another advantage: now, if you call `within_range?` on an object that it doesn't know about, it will actually *tell* you that it doesn't know what to do by raising a `NoMethodError`:

```
[].within_range?(3..30)
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `within_range?' for []:Array
```

The old version was missing an `else` clause, so it would have just returned `nil` which evaluates to `false` in a boolean context, which means that the error would probably have gone undetected.

There is even more we can do: there is actually nothing here that restricts the method from only working with whole numbers, it could just as easily work with floating point numbers, rationals or even complex numbers. So, instead of defining the second method on `Integer`, we could instead define it on `Numeric`.

But if you think about it: there actually isn't even anything that requires it to be a number *at all*, it could in fact be *any object*, so we could even define it on `Object`.

This brings me to the last two problems I have with this method, which are related to each other: I think the name for the `String` version is misleading, and I don't like that the method does completely different things despite its name being the same.

For an integer (or *any* object, if we define the method on `Object`), the method checks whether or not the integer (or object) *itself* is within the range. But for a string, the method *does not* check whether or not the string *itself* is within the range, rather it checks whether the *length* of the string is within the range. This is completely non-obvious and surprising to me:

```
  2.within_range?(1..3)     # => true
'B'.within_range?('A'..'C') # => false
```

I, and I suspect pretty much everybody else who reads that piece of code, would expect *both* of those to be `true`. The fact that `B` is not between `A` and `C` is completely confusing.

That's what I meant above: the method does two different things despite having the same name. Also, in the case of the string, the method name implies that it checks whether the string is within a certain range, but it actually checks whether the string *length* is within an certain range, and there is absolutely no indication in the method name that this is the case.

A much better name would be `length_within_range?`, and you would call it like so:

```
'B'.length_within_range?(1..2) # => true
'B'.within_range?('A'..'C')    # => true
```

[Assuming that `within_range?` is defined on `Object`.]

This makes it very clear to everyone reading the code that we are comparing the *length* of the string and not the string itself.

However, now there really isn't much difference between

```
str.length_within_range?(3..30)
str.length.within_range?(3..30)
```

Which means we can get rid of the string version altogether, leaving us only with the `Object` version.

The `Object` version, in turn, doesn't really do anything except flipping argument and receiver around, so we might just as well write

```
(3..30).include?(str.length)
```

and get rid of the whole thing altogether.

Comment: Thank you for that well written and great explonation. Now things are more clearer for me. You also made me laugh about the clothes :)
As you say i really don't need that method (yeah, i learned that it is a method). I'm just new to ruby but you explained things really good so i have learned new things today, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying is not just creating a new function. You are trying to add a **new method** to `String`.

To do that you can put your function `within_range?` into a new module and then include that module into the classes you want.

Normally this is done by calling the `include` method, but since you cannot call `String.include` or change the source code of the `String` or `Integer` class, you have to cheat and use the `send` method.

```
String.send(:include, YourModule)
Integer.send(:include, YourModule)
```

That way the `String` and the `Integer` classes get all the methods defined in `YourModule`.

For more in-depth information try this article: [Why Ruby’s Mixins Gives Rails an Advantage over Java Frameworks](http://www.innovationontherun.com/why-rubys-mixins-gives-rails-an-advantage-over-java-frameworks/)

Comment: okey, so should i add a new helper to my rails app or where should i put my new module and where should i add the "send" code?
Sorry, im kinda new to ruby and rails

Comment: I'd put it in the lib folder and the send calls either into boot.rb or environment.rb (Careful: Changes in the lib folder require a restart before they become visible to the application)

Comment: Why use send instead of String.include?

Comment: @ryeguy: `Module#include` is private.

Answer (score 4):

The function does not somehow add itself to the object class. I'm going to assume you want to add it to `Object` since you have an `is_a` call in there. You have to reopen it:

```
class Object
  def within_range?(range)
    if is_a?(String)
      (range).include?(size)
    elsif is_a?(Integer)
      (range).include?(self)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using a module is the best answer.  Alternatively, and less OO, write your method this way:

```
def within_range?(obj, range)
  case obj
  when String  then range.include?(obj.size)
  when Integer then range.include?(obj)
  end
end
```

and call it like:

```
str = "string here"
puts "'#{str}' is within the range!" if within_range?(str, 3..30)
```

Answer (score -1):

Like it mentions, it cannot find the method called 'within_range' for the String class. You need to add the method to the String class.

```
class String
 def within_range?(range)
  if self.is_a?(String)
    (range).include?(self.size)
  elsif self.is_a?(Integer)
    (range).include?(self)
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: He wants it on the object class, not the string class. Else there wouldn't be an `is_a?` check in there.

Comment: @ryeguy: No, he wants two methods, one on `String` and one on `Integer`. The `is_a?` is merely duplicating Ruby's method dispatch functionality.